# Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for output file #0 (360p.m3u 8) has not been used for any stream.

Tags: ffmpeg

I am receiving this warning from ffmpeg. The job runs and all the videos seem to output correctly. I have 2 hls, 1 mp4 with overlay + A single thumbnail.

The warning:

Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 500x38, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for output file #0 (360p.m3u
8) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type
 (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of s
ome encoder which was not actually used for any stream.

The windows batch command:

ffmpeg -loglevel info -threads 2 -hide_banner -y -i SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4 -i ecocastvideo-overlay-shadow-white-500.png^
       -filter_complex "[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7,scale=iw*0.7:-1[wm];[0:v][wm]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-10:(main_h-overlay_h)-30,split=3[a][b][c];[a]scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[a];[b]scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[b];[c]scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[c]"^
        -map "[a]" -map 0:v -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -preset veryfast -sc_threshold 0 -g 72 -keyint_min 72 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:a 96k -hls_flags single_file 360p.m3u8^
        -map "[b]" -map 0:v -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -preset veryfast -sc_threshold 0 -g 72 -keyint_min 72 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:a 96k -hls_flags single_file 720p.m3u8^
    -map "[c]" -map 0:v -c:v h264 -profile:v main -preset veryfast 720.mp4^
    -map 0:v -y -ss 0.5 -vframes 1 -an -s 120x90 -ss 30 thumbname-00001.png

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-b:a 96k` from your command. You haven't mapped any audio. If you meant to, add `-map 0:a` for each output where audio is required.